# pandas listing same indexes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

if a table has the same index 3 times in a row, I want it to fetch me this dataframe.

example

```
index  var1
1        a     
2        b    
2        c
2        d
3        e
2        f
5        g
2        f
```

After the code

expected output

```
index  var1
2       b
2       c
2       d
```

Comment: That's a pretty interesting problem! How do you think it could be solved? SO is not a coding service. Show what you have tried, explain the problems you have encountered, what's stopping you from solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us identify the blocks of consecutive indices using `cumsum`, then group and `transform` with `count` to find the size of each block then select the rows where the block size `> 2`

```
b = df['index'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df[b.groupby(b).transform('count') > 2]
```

---

```
   index var1
1      2    b
2      2    c
3      2    d
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to split data frame on the diff index, check size of each chunk and filter out chunks with sizes smaller then threshold and then recombine them:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
diff_indices = np.flatnonzero(df['index'].diff().ne(0))

diff_indices
# array([0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int32)

pd.concat([chunk for chunk in np.split(df, diff_indices) if len(chunk) >= 3])
   index var1
1      2    b
2      2    c
3      2    d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign consecutive rows to same value by comparing with next and `cumsum`. Then groupby consecutive rows and keep the group where number of rows are 3 times

```py
m = df['index'].ne(df['index'].shift()).cumsum()
out = df.groupby(m).filter(lambda col: len(col) == 3)
```

```
print(out)

   index var1
1      2    b
2      2    c
3      2    d
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more solution on top of the ones above (this one is more generalizable, since it selects ALL slices that meet the given criterium):

```
import pandas as pd

df['diff_index'] = df['index'].diff(-1) # calcs the index diff
df = df.fillna(999) # get rid of NaNs
df['diff_index'] = df['diff_index'].astype(int) # convert the diff to int

df_selected = [] # create a list of all dfs we're going to slice

l = list(df['diff_index'])

for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[i] == 0 and l[i+1] == 0: # if 2 consecutive 0s are found, get the slice
        df_temp = df[df.index.isin([i,i+1,i+2])]
        del df_temp['diff_index']
        df_selected.append(df_temp) # append the slice to our list 

print(df_selected) # list all identified data frames (in your example, there will be only one

[   index var1
 1      2    b
 2      2    c
 3      2    d]
```